# Using Powershell to read a delimited file and output a single column

Tags: powershell, export

I have a text file that I would like to read with Powershell and output the 1st field. The file has no headers and looks like:

```
"12345","11122333","R","Somebody, Joe"
"987432","55533111","R","Nobody, Sam"
```

I would like the output to a new file to look like:

```
12345

987432
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Import-Csv` cmdlet has a `Header` parameter to which you can pass desired property names. Specify those, and then use `ForEach-Object` or `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to grab only the desired property value

```
Import-Csv .\file.csv -Header ID,Number,Letter,Name |Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID
```

Comment: This provides the correct output on the screen, put how do I send the output to another file name

Comment: Used Out-File to solve the output to another file issue.